# Throwing salt above one's shoulder

Tags: minhag, salt, tradition

I would like to know if such a practice has of any sort a Jewish origin found in our Rabbinic literature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is superstition.**

aish.com [explains](https://aish.com/judaism-and-common-superstitions/)

> **This old fashioned superstition believes that spilling salt is bad
> luck – and that if you do, throwing some salt over your left shoulder
> will ward off misfortune**. In the Middle Ages, salt was extremely rare
> and expensive, and spilling it was seen as a great loss. Linking
> spilled salt with bad luck also might date to early Christian
> tradition which saw spilled salt as an evil omen.
>
> **In contrast, salt has positive connotations in Judaism.** Salt was a
> fixture in the ancient Temple in Jerusalem; this tradition continues
> today when we place salt on our Shabbat tables and sprinkle some over
> our challah before eating bread. Salt is preserver, and dipping bread
> into salt signifies elevating the physical and channeling it to a
> spiritual end, transforming the transient material world into
> something eternal. The Jewish people are also compared to salt: like
> salt, the Jewish people never grow stale, but endure forever. So feel
> free to pour that salt.